# When is it appropriate to describe research as "recent"?

Tags: citations

I want to write: *"A recent study ..."*,

The particular study I want to cite was published two years ago. I don't think that this is very recent in terms of journal appearances. But it is the *most* recent I could find compared to similar studies, which is what I want to emphasize.

But what are the general semantics of "recent" when referencing sources?

Comment: If the date of the study matters, why not "A study from 2014...."?

Comment: The date can be made out from the bibliography, so it would be redundant to add that information to the sentence.

Comment: It is an ineffective way of saying "This is important!"  As a reviewer I would probably tolerate descriptions of anything from the past ten years as "recent."

Comment: In my mind recent is anything that is new enough that it hasn't been fully absorbed (worked its way into later research, publications and into people's minds). That might depend on recent to whom -- a 20 year-old mathematical theory might well be too recent to have fully worked its way into engineering practice, so if you're writing to the engineering audience it could be appropriate to call it recent.

Comment: Redundancy is not a bad thing in academic writing.

Comment: Keep in mind that recent to you may not be recent to a future reader.  If you have something more specific to convey ("most recent at the time of writing", "unsettled", "currently the hip and trendy thing that gets grants"), you'd be best served being more specific.  Otherwise, your reader will have to look at your paper's publication date and try to work out what you meant from context.

Comment: @thrau If putting the date is redundant, isn't calling the study "recent" redundant too? The reader knows today's date, can work out the date of the study from the bibliography, and can perform the mental arithmetic necessary to know how many years ago the study was published...

Comment: @mdiener - The best part about your suggestion, I think, is that, 10 or 20 years from now, the wording would be as accurate as it is today.

Comment: I also think it depends on the field.  In astronomy, for example, a two-year old study could be considered recent when examining galaxy evolution, but a two-year old study on exoplanet populations is likely already quite outdated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good question. The semantics of the word "recent", in general, and in academic writing, in particular, is not clearly defined (that is, fuzzy), which makes its practical use quite tricky, as evidenced by your question.

While @vonbrand's answer offers some valuable insights, such as considering the *fluidity* of a particular scientific field or domain, I would suggest a more practical solution to this problem, as follows. Consider *literature* that you reference in a particular paper. What is the **temporal range** of the sources? I think that this aspect could guide you in to where the word "recent" is appropriate and where not so much.

For example, if you cite sources from the current century as well as 1930s, then a paper from 2010 should be considered recent, but not one from 1950. If, on the other hand, your temporal range of references is rather narrow, say, recent 20 years, then you should refer to as *"recent"* for sources that are from approximately last 4-5 years. You can come up with your own *rule of thumb* (10-20% of the total range sounds pretty reasonable). The most important aspect would be not the actual value (for the rule of thumb), but rather your **consistency** in applying it throughout the paper.

Comment: @thrau: My pleasure! Thank you for kind words and accepting.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the area. If you are talking about slow moving areas, "recent" could be a decade ago; for something that moves fast, what was published last year is old hat.

Perhaps the easiest way out is to be more specific, "a study three years back..." (besides, the study might be several years back, or be a decade long study, but the journal issue just came out, so the publication date isn't necessarily telling).

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, the meaning of 'recent' depends on the topic of study. What is considered recent in mathematics may not be considered recent enough for computer science. My computer science professors have generally stuck with anything five years old as being the 'oldest' an article can be. Two to three years is generally better, especially in the tech field as things progress at a much higher rate. A good thing to look out for is when an article might pass the 5 year mark, someone will most likely have adapted the methodology or research findings in a more recent article. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you refer to something that has a precise date, you should be precise. I see no advantage in writing "A recent study showed..." over "The study X from 2010 showed..." The latter contains more information and reads as least as good (in my opinion even better, because it's more precise). A similar case is "The problem posed by X at the meeting Y in 2010..." (better than "The recently posed problem...").

One case in which "recent" could make sense is "The field X has attracted much attention recently" because usually one can not pin down an exact date for this event. However, in most cases this reads more like a self-perpetuating empty statement (if there is a simple reason why the reader should care about the field X then give that!). I have to admit that I myself also wrote sentences like this, but looking back it reads a bit weird. Nowadays, if I read "this field has attracted much attention recently" I really read that the authors do not know a good reason why their problem is interesting but feel that they should.

Comment: On a slightly related note, how would you feel about "This field has attracted much attention recently because *reasons*"?

Comment: I would say, the more precise the better. Probably in such a sentence just giving the reason that you feel that make the field exciting is enough. The additional information that these exciting facts resulted in "much attention recently" seems not so important. I would find it even better if the sentence would tell that the field is *relevant* and not that its fancy right now.